# Discouraging zero-effort 'my code's broken, fix it for me' type questions

Tags: discussion, down-votes, asking-questions

I just came across a question on SO that was essentialy: 'my program stops here' and a short blob of code. Nothing else. He hand't even bothered to properly punctuate the four-word question. There wasn't a description of the problem, stack trace, error message, or any indication which line was producing the error.

Several people pointed out that if the user wanted a good answer, he'd have to invest more effort.

But somebody answered anyway. Sure it wasn't a good answer, but the point is that some people will do anything for rep, so regardless of how bad the question is, there'll always be an answer or two. I downvoted the question after leaving a comment, as did several other people.

And then I checked out the asker's profile: almost 20 questions, one upvote, 20% accept rate.

This user did not deserve to get any help. Is there anything that can be done besides downvoting to put a stop to this kind of behavior? Maybe some kind of warning when a user has a certain downvote/question ratio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If things are really as bad as you describe: downvoting helps. This [will eventually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56817/can-we-prevent-some-of-the-low-quality-questions-from-entering-our-system/60294#60294) get the user a "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account":

> Questions from IP addresses or accounts with a history of extremely poor questions will no longer be accepted. This is intended to weed out the worst quality questions.
>
> (hint hint, question votes matter, so please continue to vote the best questions up and vote the worst questions down.)

Comment: That's great. I had no idea that there was a de facto banning system in place.